# Can I lower a Chrome tab's memory capacity?

Tags: google-chrome

Websites often take up too much memory and can make the browser slow. I'd prefer it if the tab didn't crash (a laggy UI is preferred). I could turn off Javascript if the site was unusable with the memory cap.

Comment: Maybe it'll soon be a moot point since the developers are working on making Chrome more memory-efficient by fully suspending tabs in background ([link](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/project-trim/Exb8Wbj8fM4)), there's also a flag to enable autodiscarding ([link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/tab-discarding?hl=en)).

Comment: good to know. I have a suspend-tab extension installed, but I'd prefer it if the tabs didn't have to close. I'm looking to use a memory cap but not have the tabs crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of functionality is not available nor would it ever be available. A feature such as memory limits per-tab is an extremely niche use and it wouldn't have a return on investment for implementing and rolling it out. The team is far better off working on the memory issues themselves and reducing their usage internally.

It is difficult to simply "cap memory" for web apps. When it is available it will get used and when it isn't then something is going to get dumped out of memory. Part of the memory issues are within the Chrome team however, some are because web developers to program responsibly and not waste user resources.

There simply isn't much in user-space that can be done here. It is up to the Chrome team to optimize internally as well as web developers being responsible and thoughtful towards what they produce.